# SQL Server simple comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I compare two of following columns:

```
Column A        Column B  Column c
10,16,56,76      56       good
2,64,74,66       77       missing
```

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be storing lists of values in a column.  You should not be storing numbers in a string.  But let me assume you have no choice in the matter, stuck with someone else's really, really, really bad decisions.

You could use `like`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when concat(',', A, ',') like concat('%,', B, ',%')
             then 'Good' else 'Missing'
        end)
from t;
```

Instead of storing the values in a *string*, you should have a separate junction table with one row per A and per entity.  Then the query would use `exists`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from junction j where j.entity_id = t.entity_id and j.a = t.b)
             then 'Good' else 'Missing'
        end)
from t;
```

This would probably have much better performance too.